# APC install with EasyPHP

Tags: php, apc, easyphp

I've been tying to follow [this](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/) guide for integrating Doctrine 2 and CI 2.
all was good until i ran "php doctrine-cli.php orm:generate-proxies" from a cmd,
and got this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()`.

after some research it looks like I don't have the AlternativePhpCache (ACP) module installed.
so i've tried every single version in downloads.php.net/pierre and they all yield the same error

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QEt3udKTSGc/Tlkgr5POw4I/AAAAAAAAEwQ/hlAhmcxshDE/123.jpg
(screenshot from my picasa as i can't upload images due to a lack of points)

**I'm using :**

- Win7 (x64)
- EasyPhp 5.3.5.0

am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: does extension=php_apc.dll is set in your php.ini?

Comment: yes. that's why im getting the alert in the first place

Comment: is the APC module shows when you display phpinfo()? which version of APC you have?

Comment: nope, i used php_apc-20110109-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip from
http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Comment: Then if it doesn't show in the phpinfo() it means the module is not laoded. Any easyphp error? hav you tried a different version?

Comment: I finally managed to solve the error by installing VC6 from t
http://downloads.php.net/pierre

now see it in the phpinfo()

APC Support enabled
Version 3.1.6-dev
APC Debugging Disabled
MMAP Support Disabled
Locking type File Locks
...

**But** i couldn't make it run from cmd (windows), i keep getting 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()

even though i have added this to my **php.ini**:
[apc]
apc.rfc1867 = on
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 128M
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl = 7200
apc.num_files_hint = 1024
**apc.enable_cli = 1**
apc.max_file_size = 200M

Comment: my last post is kinda messed up, i was complaining about not being able to run from cli even though i have added the paramters to php.ini, when Apache runs am APC command it is fine.

Comment: you might have to use the php.ini file when you run the command: C:\php\cli\php.exe -c C:\path\to\php.ini myscript.php

Comment: Is this APC module compiled for the same PHP version that you are using?

Comment: This answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217502/doctrine-command-line-create-schema

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Xammp. I made a search on google and found http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ web site. According to my operating system specification and PHP version I chose the suitable file which was php_apc-20110109-5.3-vc9-x86.zip (2011-01-09 12:16 -0800) for me and downloaded it. I extracted the file to my **Xammp/php/ext** folder as **php_apc.dll**. After all, I edited my php.ini file and add **extension=php_apc.dll** to extension section in `php.ini`. If you need you can add the following configuration.

**[APC]**

```
 - apc.enabled = 1 
 - apc.shm_segments = 1 
 - apc.shm_size = 64
 - apc.max_file_size = 16M 
 - apc.stat = 1
```

That worked out for me. If this is not going to work for you, then you may check your operating system(especially x86 or x64) and php version (5.2.* or 5.3.*). I hope this information will help you. Have a great day guys.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks. In the APC zip file from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ there are two subfolders, `nts` and `ts`. The one in `nts` didn't work, but the file in `ts` worked. After copying that to the `etc` folder, adding `extension=php_apc.dll` to php.ini, and restarting Apache it was enabled and working.