# Doctrine command line create schema

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine

My first time using Doctrine + CodeIgniter and trying to use orm:schema-tool:create command I get this error message:

```
C:\>C:\xampp\php\php.exe  c:\xampp\htdocs\doctrine\application\doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in C:\xampp\htdocs\doctrine\application\libraries\Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache.php on line 52
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, it was pretty obvious.

On my Doctrine.php I had a line trying to use cache using APC and I don't have APC installed...commented those lines and problem solved.

Hope it helps.